# Pandas group by interval

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column called `month`, that contains the number of the month from 1-12.

Example:

```
  Index     month  
  0          1        
  1          9         
  2          12
```

I want to split this column up into a quarter interval:
`1-3`
`4-6`
`7-9`
`10-12`

so each row gets put into one of these intervals.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the quotient operator to split by quarter:

```
df['quarter'] = df['month'] // 4 + 1
```

Or you can use [`numpy.digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) to explicitly define bins:

```
df['quarter'] = np.digitize(df['month'], [3, 6, 9], right=True) + 1

print(df)

   Index  month  quarter
0      0      1        1
1      1      9        3
2      2     12        4
```

Comment: Wow, that was almost too simple `df['quarter'] = df['month'] // 4 + 1` !

Answer (score 2):

You can using `pd.cut`

```
pd.cut(df.month,[0,4,7,10,13],right=False)
Out[298]: 
0      [0, 4)
1     [7, 10)
2    [10, 13)
Name: month, dtype: category
Categories (4, interval[int64]): [[0, 4) < [4, 7) < [7, 10) < [10, 13)]
```

Or

```
pd.to_datetime(df.month,format='%m').dt.quarter
Out[308]: 
0    1
1    3
2    4
Name: month, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a quick function to do this then apply it to the DataFrame that will generate the quarter month ranges as a string.

```
def quarter_range(x):
    q = int(np.floor(x / 4.) + 1)
    qr = "-".join([str(q), str(q+2)])
    return qr

df["quarter_label"] = df["month"].apply(quarter_range)
```